Slack Bot Sends New Message Instead of Updating Original
I’m building a Slack bot using FastAPI that performs a long-running task and updates the original message in Slack after the task completes. However, instead of updating the original message, it sends a new one.
Expected Behavior:

The bot should display an initial message ("Processing your request...") and later update this same message with the final result.

Actual Behavior:

The initial message is sent correctly, but when the task completes, a new message is posted instead of updating the original one.

Code Implementation:
FastAPI Endpoint:
@app.post("/greet")
async def greet_user(
    background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
    user_name: str = Form(...),
    response_url: str = Form(...)  # Provided by Slack
):
    background_tasks.add_task(
        process_long_running_task,
        user_name=user_name,
        response_url=response_url
    )
    return JSONResponse(
        content={
            "response_type": "ephemeral",
            "text": "Processing your request..."
        }
    )

Background Task:
async def process_long_running_task(user_name: str, response_url: str):
    await asyncio.sleep(15)  # Simulate long-running task
    final_response = {
        "response_type": "in_channel",
        "text": f"Hii, {user_name}. How can I help you today?"
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        await client.post(response_url, json=final_response)

Question:
How can I ensure the bot updates the original message instead of posting a new one? Do I need to use additional parameters or a different API method?
Thank you for any help!

https://api.slack.com/messaging/modifying#updating I'd look here. From reading the docs, it looks like you need to keep track of the channel id and the message timestamp as the arguments to identify the original message you want to edit.
